# Android EditText value constraint

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want that my `EditText` will accept float value from a given range and accepts only two digit after decimal point, say from 0 to 99.99

In my xml, I have included

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

kindly help.

Comment: see EditText.setFilters()

Comment: Seems the "duplicate" accepted answer has weird side effect...

Answer (score 0):

You should add addTextChangedListener to your editText
something like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {

            }
        });
```

According to your logic you can implement the input check. for example:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    String number = editText.getText().toString();
    if (number .length != 0) {
        int number  = Integer.parseInt(added_number);

        if (number > 99)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Not more than 99", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

hope it helps.
If you are looking to test the input on the fly, you should override onTextChanged.
i have some example code if you like

Comment: What he needs are filters.

Comment: okay, after some reading , filters are the easiest way to go.